# download link with get vars

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler

How can I download page on this link

http://www.kayak.com/s/search/air?ai=kayaksample&do=y&ft=ow&ns=n&cb=e&pa=1&l1=ZAG&t1=a&df=dmy&d1=4/10/2010&depart_flex=exact&r1=y&l2=LON&t2=a&d2=11/10/2010&return_flex&r2=y

Link changes to short version (for example www.kayak.com/r/OcJdUd>) after some time ...

I tried to download page with fopen command and Curl lib but nothing.

So is there any solution ?

Thanks!

Comment: did you check what response this URL returns? is it an HTTP 200, or some redirection? BTW, curl should have a way to tell you this, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Site returns Http status 302 - moved temporarily, so you should follow redirections. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php for **CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION** and **CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS**